# HTML, PHP: Change contents of SELECT listbox depending on selection in other SELECT listbox

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a form that allows my user to send a date to the server.
I'm using one SELECT listbox to display the months. I would then like the other SELECT listbox to display the days of the month accurately depending on which month was selected (30 or 31 days, 28 or 29 for February).

How do you suggest I do this?

Alternatively if there is a smarter way of doing this than with listboxes I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: How about using a calendar widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel, it's easier for you to leverage existing solutions people have come up with. Here's a good one:

http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/

Comment: Thank you that indeed looks interesting.
By any chance do you know if I'm allowed to use this on a website I'm making money off of?

Comment: It's dual-licensed under MIT and GPL, which does have legal implications. I'd suggest looking into it or finding a plugin that's MIT-only, as the GPL license states you MUST make all of your source code available if you have any GPL-code in it.